# Xcode breakpoint shell command argument length

Tags: swift, xcode, shell, breakpoints

Trying to pass a large string to a shell script using a breakpoint in Xcode

```
let value = Array(repeating: "a", count: 1500).joined()
let string = "{\"key\": \"\(value)\"}"
```

Unfortunately, the string is being truncated. Is this limitation documented and can it be overcome?

[image: breakpoint]

Comment: If all else fails you could use the LLDB Python API to do this, kind of [like this](https://twitter.com/jtbandes/status/599263355308613634)

Comment: That looks quite powerful. Thanks!

Comment: @LescaiIonel Did you ever solve this? I'm running into similar problems.

Comment: @LescaiIonel I figured it out. I've added an answer below so let me know if this solves the issue for you as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been nearly a year since you asked this, and I'm not sure if it will solve your question, but I've recently had a similar problem so thought I'd share my solution.

I had two issues:

1. LLDB was truncating any arguments to my shell script (and string variables printed in the console using `po foo`) to 1023 characters. I believe this is the issue to which your question relates.
2. Xcode was incorrectly confusing a comma `,` in my string as a separator for multiple arguments (e.g. passing `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` as arguments to the script wouldn't work correctly if any of the variables contained a `,` as Xcode would try to create another argument).

So, **firstly**, the LLDB issue...

It seems that by default LLDB has a limit on the character length that it will print to the console (or pass to a shell script via a breakpoint argument) of around 1023 characters. You can easily change this to something larger by setting another breakpoint *before* the breakpoint that uses your variable and running `(lldb) set set target.max-string-summary-length 10000` in the console. This can be a bit annoying so I created a `~/.lldbinit` file and placed `set set target.max-string-summary-length 10000` in there instead so I don't have to keep setting it in the console.

**Secondly**, the comma issue...

Inside the `Edit breakpoint...` menu that you provided a screenshot of above there is the option to not only provide a path to a script but to also provide arguments. I can see from your question that you provided the argument `@string@`. For my script, I was passing multiple arguments, which Xcode allows you to do using a comma separated list, e.g. `@foo@, @bar@, @baz@`. Each of these arguments was a string.

I noticed that sometimes one or more of these strings would truncate if they contained a comma: `,`.

So the string:

`{ "num_friends" : "7" }`

would be passed to my script as expected. But the string:

`{ "num_friends" : "7", "num_deleted_friends" : "1" }`

would truncate and **would be passed to my script as two separate arguments**. It seems that Xcode would split any string with a `,` even when entered using `@string@`.

I validated this in my script by simply using something like:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
    echo "===="
done
```

Where `$@` expands to contain each argument. From this I could see that  `@string@` was being correctly passed to my script but separated as multiple arguments wherever there was a `,`. So if `@string@` contained a comma my script would print:

```
@"{ \"num_friends\" : \"7\"
====
\"num_deleted_friends\" : \"1\" }"
```

instead of what I expected which was:

```
@"{ \"num_friends\" : \"7\", \"num_deleted_friends\" : \"1\" }"
```

So it seems like it might be a bug in how Xcode passes strings inside `@` expressions in the breakpoint editor window.

My crude solution has been to just replace any commas with another character and then replace them back again inside my script. There's probably a better way to do this but I don't require it for my needs.